# Consulta para mostrar horario de clases en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenas tardes, estoy tratando de generar un horario de clases y llevo varios días sin poder generar el horario mediante una consulta en MySQL.

La consulta que estoy realizando en MySQL es la siguiente:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(h.hora_inicio,"%H:%i")," - ",DATE_FORMAT(h.hora_fin,"%h:%i")) hora,
CASE WHEN ho.dia="Lunes" THEN ho.nombre ELSE '' END Lunes,
CASE WHEN ho.dia="Martes" THEN ho.nombre ELSE '' END Martes,
CASE WHEN ho.dia="Miercoles" THEN ho.nombre ELSE '' END Miercoles,
CASE WHEN ho.dia="Jueves" THEN ho.nombre ELSE '' END Jueves,
CASE WHEN ho.dia="Viernes" THEN ho.nombre ELSE '' END Viernes,
CASE WHEN ho.dia="Sabado" THEN ho.nombre ELSE '' END Sabado FROM    (
        SELECT h.codigo_hora,h.codigo_docentes,c.nombre,h.dia 
          FROM horario h 
    INNER JOIN curso c 
            ON c.codigo_curso=h.codigo_curso
) ho 
INNER JOIN docentes d 
        ON d.codigo_docentes=ho.codigo_docentes 
INNER JOIN hora h 
        ON h.codigo_hora=ho.codigo_hora 
  GROUP BY hora 
  ORDER BY hora ASC
```

El resultado obtenido al ejecutar la consulta es el siguiente: [image: HORARIO DE CLASES]

Tengo varios registros de mis cursos asignados a docentes en diferentes horas pero no me muestra como debería de ser el horario de clases, en varias celdas me sale vacío y no sé en qué estaría mal la consulta, ya que tengo varios registros. Ojala puedan ayudarme a solucionar este problema.

Comment: hola me podrias ayudar que tabla no mas utilizaste

Comment: @darwin Las respuestas no deben usarse para pedir clarificaciones o detalles adicionales. Lee [answer] para más información y consejos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas usar una función de agregación para las columnas que no estás usando en el `GROUP BY` (en la mayoría de los motores de bases de datos es obligación, MySQL lo permite, pero te entrega resultados como estos). El código sería:

```
SELECT  CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(h.hora_inicio,"%H:%i")," - ",DATE_FORMAT(h.hora_fin,"%h:%i")) hora,
        MAX(CASE WHEN ho.dia = 'Lunes' THEN ho.nombre ELSE '' END) Lunes,
        MAX(CASE WHEN ho.dia = 'Martes' THEN ho.nombre ELSE '' END) Martes,
        MAX(CASE WHEN ho.dia = 'Miercoles' THEN ho.nombre ELSE '' END) Miercoles,
        MAX(CASE WHEN ho.dia = 'Jueves' THEN ho.nombre ELSE '' END) Jueves,
        MAX(CASE WHEN ho.dia = 'Viernes' THEN ho.nombre ELSE '' END) Viernes,
        MAX(CASE WHEN ho.dia = 'Sabado' THEN ho.nombre ELSE '' END) Sabado 
FROM (  SELECT  h.codigo_hora,
                h.codigo_docentes,
                c.nombre,
                h.dia 
        FROM horario h 
        INNER JOIN curso c 
            ON c.codigo_curso = h.codigo_curso) ho 
INNER JOIN docentes d 
    ON d.codigo_docentes = ho.codigo_docentes 
INNER JOIN hora h 
    ON h.codigo_hora = ho.codigo_hora 
GROUP BY CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(h.hora_inicio,"%H:%i")," - ",DATE_FORMAT(h.hora_fin,"%h:%i")) 
ORDER BY CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(h.hora_inicio,"%H:%i")," - ",DATE_FORMAT(h.hora_fin,"%h:%i")) ASC;
```

Comment: Acabo de ejecutar tu consulta y me muestra menos registros, solo muestra 3 cursos en diferentes horas. Me muestra más campos vacíos ojala puedas ayudarme

Comment: @JuanVásquezVentura Tienes algunos datos de prueba para poder ayudarte?

Comment: Si tengo datos, de que manera te podría proporcionar para que me ayudes

Comment: @JuanVásquezVentura puedes postear un ejemplo de tu tabla con datos en sqlfiddle.com o [acá](http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler)

Comment: @JuanVásquezVentura Listo, el problema era simplemente que había que usar `MAX` en vez de `MIN`

Comment: Muchas gracias está perfecto. Muy agradecido por tu ayuda.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46269/discussion-between-juan-vasquez-ventura-and-lamak).